Masm: Reading video memory directly in ax=12h 640*480 16 color vga mode
I already have a function for writing the dot(cx, dx) directly in video memory and its work. Now I’m trying to write a function to read the color of given coordinate and return its color to al(from 0 to 15). I use the last step of write function and retrieve data from video memory, but it doesn’t seems to give desired results.
vmemr PROC
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di
    mov ax, 0A000h ; video memory start point
    mov es, ax

    ;offset=y*(640/8)+(x/8)
    mov ax, dx
    mov bx, 80
    mul bx
    mov di, ax

    mov ax, cx
    mov bx, 8
    div bx
    add di, ax ; di=offset

    mov al, es:[di]
    pop di
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret

vmemr ENDP


I wrote a test program that first print a couple dots on the screen, and use this function to print the whole screen with another color while keeping the old dots. It appears to be detecting Dots on the screen but it does not print for around 8 pixels. I think the problem derived from the offset x/8.
Also i can’t seems to find any data in memory section a000 in code view even when i print the whole screen. This also prevent me from debugging further.


I use the last step of write function and retrieve data from video memory, but it doesn’t seems to give desired results.


mov al, es:[di]
...
pop ax
ret


Notwithstanding the pop ax that anyway was destroying what you were trying to retrieve, you can't address the graphics memory at A0000h in a straightforward fashion and hope to get the color for a single pixel.
The 640x480 16-color video mode 12h is a planar video mode. The 4 bits that make up your color value in the range [0,15] are spread around into 4 different memory buffers ('planes'). And to make this an efficient scheme the VGA graphics adapter also packs 8 neighbouring pixels together in a byte.
What your mov al, es:[di] instruction loads is the combined information for 8 neighbouring pixels. If you never touched the ReadMapSelect register, then normally these bits would pertain to plane 0. You need to fetch similar information from the other planes too, combine it and filter for your desired pixel. I show all of this in the below code snippets.
My codes assume that the ES segment register is already set to A000h, that the color is or will be stored at [ss:bp], that the AX register passes the Y coordinate, and that the BX register passes the X coordinate.
; IN (ax,bx,ss:bp,es) OUT ()
ReadRealDot:
    push  ax cx dx di
    call  CalcA             ; -> CL CH DX DI
    mov   ax, 4
    out   dx, al            ; ReadMapSelect register
    inc   dx                ; GraphicsController data port
    dec   ax                ; Plane 3
.a: out   dx, al            ; -> ReadMapSelect register
    test  [es:di], ch
    setnz cl
    shl   ah, 1
    add   ah, cl
    sub   al, 1             ; Plane 2 then 1 then 0
    jnb   .a
    mov   [bp], ah
    pop   di dx cx ax
    ret
; --------------------------
; IN (ax,bx,ss:bp,es) OUT ()
WriteRealDot:
    push  ax cx dx di
    call  CalcA             ; -> CL CH DX DI
    mov   ax, 0205h
    out   dx, ax            ; -> Mode register (mode 2)
    mov   ah, ch            ; PixelMask
    mov   al, 8
    out   dx, ax            ; -> BitMask register
    mov   dl, [es:di]       ; Dummy read
    mov   al, [bp]
    mov   [es:di], al       ; Write color
    pop   di dx cx ax
    ret
; --------------------------
; IN (ax,bx) OUT (cl,ch,dx,di)
CalcA:
    mov   dx, ax            ; Y
    mov   di, bx            ; X
    imul  dx, 80
    shr   di, 3
    add   di, dx            ; -> DI=PixelAddress
    mov   cl, bl
    mov   ch, 1000_0000b
    and   cl, 0000_0111b
    shr   ch, cl            ; -> CH=PixelMask
    mov   dx, 03CEh         ; GraphicsController
    ret


If you're expecting to get the result in al, you might want to consider not overwriting it with a pop before returning(1) :-)
mov al, es:[di]   ; This gets the color value ...
:
pop ax            ; ... and this overwrites it.
ret

It's okay to preserve and restore all registers for something like setting a pixel (where nothing is returned) but, to get a pixel value, it's probably better to treat changes to ax as a natural consequence of the call.

(1) For anyone not knowledgeable of the x86-style registers, ah is the upper half of ax while al is the lower half, so changing ah or al also changes ax. In fact this "sharing" of bits between registers carries on in the x86 processors up through the 32-bit eax and 64-bit rax:
 63            32 31    16 15 8 7  0 <- bits
+----------------+--------+----+----+
|                |        | ah | al |
+----------------+--------+----+-^--+
|                |        |   ax    |
+----------------+--------+------^--+
|                |       eax        |
+----------------+---------------^--+
|               rax                 |
+--------------------------------^--+
                                 |
Changing this bit in any of {al, ax, eax, rax} will
affect all of them (for the 64-bit processors,
obviously there's no rax in the 32-bit ones for example).


Might be the OP didn't realise that al is the lower half of ax.

Good point, @ecm, have added an explanatory footnote.
